# ERROR: Cannot set priority of journalnode process 6520

Tags: docker, hadoop

I have three physical nodes with docker installed on them. I have configured a high  available hadoop cluster among these nodes. The configuration is like this:
Core-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
     <value>/tmp/hadoop/dfs/jn</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:2181,10.32.0.2:2181,10.32.0.3:2181</value>
  </property>
```

Hdfs-site.xml:

```
   <property>
     <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
     <value>mycluster</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>
     <value>nn1,nn2</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:8020</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
     <value>10.32.0.2:8020</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:50070</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
     <value>10.32.0.2:50070</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.
      ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
     <value>qjournal:// 
     10.32.0.1:8485;10.32.0.2:8485;10.32.0.3:8485/mycluster</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.enable</name>
     <value> false </value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
     <value>sshfence</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
     <value>/home/hdfs/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>
     <value>30000</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
     <value>hdfs</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname- 
     check</name>
     <value>false</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
   </property>
```

I made **hdfs** user and **ssh-passwordless**. When I want to start journalnode to format namenode via this command:

```
    sudo /opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs --daemon start journalnode
```

I receive this error:

> ERROR: Cannot set priority of journalnode process 6520

Would you please what is wrong with my configuration to receive the error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I check the log in **/opt/hadoop/logs/*.log** and see this line:

> Cannot make directory of **/tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode**.

First, I put configuration of journal node directory to **hdfs-site.xml** and made a journal node directory. Then I started journal node again and I faced with this error:

> directory is not writable. So, I ran these commands to make the directory writable:

```
  chmod 777 /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode
  chown -R root /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode
```

Then I could start journal node.